# SSL Network Extender Applet is trying to connect to http://127.0.0.1:7776/ before crashing

Tags: ssl, vpn, remote-access

OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.8 (Tikanga)
FireFox version: FireFox ESR, 17.0.3, x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
java version verification by java.com: Your Java version: Version 6 Update 45

Problem:  SSL Network Extender Applet crashes on FireFox. I guess the most interesting part of the stack trace as it seen in the Java Console is:

> 02/06/2014 04:08:11[SNXNetMode] Checking communication to SNX Network
>   Mode 02/06/2014 04:08:11[Component] Trying to create socket to
>   127.0.0.1:7776 network: Connecting `http://127.0.0.1:7776/` with proxy=DIRECT 02/06/2014 04:08:11[Component] Could not connect
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)

Any idea why it is trying to connect to the local machine and fail eventually?